# How to update a value, given a key in a java hashmap made of LinkedLists?

Tags: java, list, linked-list, hashmap

This is my `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<String, LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>> partitionMap = new HashMap<String, LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>>();
```

I know that using the put method could work, like:

```
hashmap.put(key, hashmap.get(key) + 1);
```

but in this example we have the `Integer`, in my case I have a `LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>>`

Is there a way to do the same?

Comment: "Is there a way to do the same?" <- Well, since you cannot add 1 to a LinkedList the answer is no ;). But you can of course get your LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>> by calling hashmap.get(key) and then modify it by calling methods on it... e.G. hashmap.get(key).add(....)

Comment: do you want to update the content of the linked list or the linked list itself ?

Comment: If I do hashmap.get(key).add(...) it returns error because the add methods return a boolean. That is the problem. I want to update the LinkedList itself.

Comment: if you are using java 8 I would recommend looking at `putIfAbsent()`, `computeIfAbsent()`, `computeIfPresent()` and `merge()`

Comment: @user840718 So? Just ignore the return value. Just calling hashmap.get(key).add(....) is enough to modify the list. They are not immutable. And if you want to replace it with a complete new object just call hashmap.put(key, new LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>()).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`put` still works the same. You can put a new pair of `String,LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>` into the map with:

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<String>> aList = new LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>();
hashmap.put("aString", aList);
```

or, more concisely

```
hashmap.put("aString", new LinkedList<>());
```

To then *modify* a linked list within the map, `get` it, and then modify it.

```
hashmap.get("aString").add(new LinkedList<String>());
```

You don't need to put the modified list back into the map. As you got a reference to the list in the map, you are modifying the list currently in the map.

---

As an aside, are you *sure* you want a `LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>`? Accessing an arbitrary LinkedList within the outer LinkedList will take linear time, which means editing the contents of one of the nested LinkedLists will take (best case) linear time, and could be as bad as quadratic.

I'd recommend an `ArrayList<List<String>>` instead (or a `List<List<String>>` instantiated as an `ArrayList<List<String>>`). That way you can access arbitrary nested lists in constant time, and the specific List implementation used in the nested lists is left open.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course:

```
LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>> list = hashmap.get(key);
LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>> updatedList = updateListValue(list);
hashmap.put(key, updatedList);
```

Now, the code for `updateListValue(LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>> list)` will of course depend on what you mean by "update a value".

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java8+ you can use the methods `compute`, `computeIfPresent` and `computeIfAbsent`

```
    HashMap<String, LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>> partitionMap = new HashMap<String, LinkedList<LinkedList<String>>>();
    partitionMap.computeIfAbsent("key-1", key -> new LinkedList<>()); //add
    System.out.println(partitionMap);
    partitionMap.computeIfPresent("key-1", (key, value) -> {value.add(new LinkedList<>()); return value;}); //update
    System.out.println(partitionMap);
```

`compute*` methods would return value

Output

```
{key-1=[]}
{key-1=[[]]}
```